# How to check if an iterable can be traversed again?

Tags: python, iterator, iterable-unpacking

Consider the following code:

```
def my_fun(an_iterable):
  for val in an_iterable:
    do_work(val)
    if some_cond(val):
       do_some_other_work(an_iterable)
       break
```

if the `an_iterable` is a `list`/`tuple`, `do_some_other_work` will get the whole list again. But if the `an_iterable` was a `iterator` or a `generator`, it will only receive rest of the items in the list. How do I differentiate between two cases? I want `do_some_other_work` to receive rest of the items only.

Comment: Would using `isinstance(obj, generator) or hasattr(obj, 'next')` work? Iterators have to support `next`, and the other checks for generator type.

Comment: Aren't there any other type of standard python objects which support only single traversing? Like a generator function?

Comment: You _could_ use `tee`, or a simpler wrapper that lets you peek one element without consuming, or one that lets you push back onto an iterator (by chain), or even just `list` as a wrapper. Then you can destructively test whether the iterator is restartable, and you still haven't lost the data (because it's in the wrapper). But this would be silly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no general way to tell whether you can iterate over an object repeatedly. File-like objects, in particular, are likely to screw up checks. Fortunately, you don't need to check this. If you just want to make sure `do_some_other_work` only gets the rest of the items, you can explicitly request an iterator:

```
def my_fun(iterable):
    iterable = iter(iterable)
    # Do whatever.
```

Comment: I agree this seems like the /right/ way to do it. Especially with how ugly the alternative is.

Comment: Which one is better or is it just a matter of taste?
`iterable = iter(iterable)` or `iterable = (val for val in iterable)` ?

Comment: @balki: `iter` is better because it says exactly what it's doing, without any unnecessary distractions. It's also more concise, and faster, and works in weird edge cases where you care about the difference between the actual iterator vs. a new iterator that happens to iterate the same things.

Comment: How about, `iterable = iter(iterable) if not hasattr(iterable,'next') else iterable` ? I am planning to use this in a recursive function, so worried if multiple wrappers of iter could be an issue

Comment: The iterator protocol specifies that `iter(it) is it` for any iterator `it`. Calling `iter` repeatedly won't generate a zillion wrapper iterators.

Comment: @balki: Why? For most iterators, `iter(iterable)` returns itself. And in the rare edge cases where that isn't true, there's probably a good reason for it. So, unless you have some special reason to avoid calling `iter`, just call it.

Comment: @user2357112 Realised that, sorry for deleting the comment.

Comment: Thanks @user2357112 and @abarnert, `iter` works great without wrappers. But the same is not true for generators. I just checked

Comment: @balki: Yes it is. I ran [this code](http://pastebin.com/qjWqdD4q) in various versions of CPython 2.5 through 3.3, PyPy, and Jython, and they all agree that `iter()` on a generator returns the generator. The same thing is true for generators created by genexprrs instead of genfuncs.

Comment: @abarnert: I suspect balki meant that `(val for val in iterable)` generates wrapper iterators, not that `iter(gen) is not gen` for a generator `gen`.

Comment: I did `gen_gen = (val for val in gen)` and `gen_gen` is not same as `gen`

Comment: @balki: Yes, that's exactly why I suggested not to use a genexpr instead of calling `iter` when you asked earlier.

Comment: `iterator` (or just `it`) is more specific so it might be a better name: `iterator = iter(iterable)`. `iter()` always returns an iterator (that is also always an iterable, but only some iterables are also iterators).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: This code deliberately overwrites the original `iterable`, so we don't have to worry about two variables.

Answer (score -1):

Consider the following snippet:

```
import types

def which(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, types.GeneratorType):
        print 'Generator'
    elif hasattr(obj, 'next') and (iter(obj) == obj):
        print 'Iterator'
    elif hasattr(obj, '__iter__'):
        print 'Iterable'
    else:
        print 'Object'

def my_gen(length):
    for i in xrange(length):
        yield i

# Reports 'Generator'
which(my_gen(10))
# Reports 'Iterable'
which(iter(xrange(10)))
# Reports 'Object'
which([i for i in xrange(10)])

with open('foo.txt', 'w+') as fout:
    for _ in xrange(10):
        fout.write('hello\n')

# Reports 'Iterable'
with open('foo.txt') as fin:
    which(fin)
```

This identifies them as 'Generator', 'Iterable' and then 'Object'

Comment: I disagree. It reports 'iterator' for me.

Comment: ...huh. File objects are their own iterators. I didn't realize they made that decision. I learned something!

Comment: `iter(obj) == obj` will only be true for iterators and iterator-like things, not all iterables, so using it to distinguish "Iterable" from "Object" is wrong. And if you want to use it to distinguish iterators from other iterables, it's not even guaranteed to do that. `if iter(obj)==obj` it's guaranteed to be non-restartable—but the converse is not true.

Comment: I was on the fence about putting the `iter(obj) == obj`, and while not strictly true, the pattern of `iter`s returning `self` is so common as to be almost always true. I think the answer's worth keeping around with this conversation.

Comment: @DanLecocq: That's not the main point; it's _not_ a pattern for general iterables (like `list`), only for iterators (like generators). So, using it to distinguish iterables from "objects" does the wrong thing _in general_, not just in special cases. And confusing the distinction between iterables and iterators in an answer to a question that's all about that distinction is a bad idea.

Comment: It sounds like you're upset with the term 'iterable' as opposed to 'iterator'. That was a typo on my part.

Comment: @DanLecocq: The whole point of this question is how to tell whether an iterable is an iterator (or iterator-like thing) or not. So it's a pretty important distinction. And, even with the name fix, your code still doesn't even attempt to distinguish iterators from other iterables, which is what the OP wanted.